# Como mostrar dados de uma session no angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou a fazer uma app móvel já tenho o login a funcionar e a guardar os valores que quero em session agora não sei e como mostrar esses valores na pagina a seguir ao login.

**Controller**

```
.controller('LoginInterno', function($scope, $http, sessionService) {
    $scope.Btnlogin= function (input){
        $http.post("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_login.php?email=" + input.email + "&password=" + input.password).success(function (data) {
            $scope.login = data;
            userInfo = {
                user_id: data.user_id,
                nome: data.nome,
                user_foto: data.user_foto,
                user_slug: data.user_slug
            };
            sessionService.set('user_id',userInfo.user_id);
            sessionService.set('nome',userInfo.nome);
            sessionService.set('user_foto',userInfo.user_foto);
            sessionService.set('user_slug',userInfo.user_slug);
            window.location = "#/app/home"
        }).
        error(function (data) {
            alert("Dados Incorrectos");
        });
    };
})
```

**sessionService.js**

```
app.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
        set:function(key,value){
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function(key){
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function(key){
            $http.post('data/destroy_session.php');
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}])
```

**Detalhes do utilizador**

```
<div class="item item-avatar" ng-controller="LoginInterno">
    <img src="mcfly.jpg">
    <h2>{{nome}}</h2>
    <p>0 Opiniões, 0 Seguidores</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro do seu controller, depois da sua função, BtnLogin, adicione uma chamada ao seu serviço systemService chamando a função 'get' que você criou passando a key (nome) que você criou no sessionStorage, e atribuindo na propriedade 'nome', que você criou para realizar o bind no html.

```
.controller('LoginInterno', function($scope, $http, sessionService) { 

   $scope.Btnlogin = function () {
           //Seu codigo.
   }


   $scope.nome = sessionService.get('nome');

}
```

Comment: Funcionou bem era mesmo isso uma coisa simples que eu estava a complicar. obrigado

Comment: precisando estou a disposição @CésarSousa